# How to read csv into a list of tuples python?

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I would like my final list to be of this form:

```
index_list=[(slice(170, 255), slice(22, 32)),
(slice(170, 255), slice(69, 79)),
(slice(170, 255), slice(118, 128)),
(slice(170, 255), slice(163, 173)),
etc
etc
etc]
```

But I want to store the tuple values in excel, so for instance, cell A1 might be

```
(slice(170, 255), slice(22, 32))
```

... and so on for all the slice tuple values. Or the cells in excel may simply have the numbered values

```
170, 255, 22, 32
```

which python could use to create tuples. I don't care what the format is in excel, I would just like to store the values there and read them as a list of tuples with that string format. The following is about as far as I was able to get:

```
with open('index_values.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:
        index_list.append(tuple(str(row).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('"','').split(', ')))
```

Comment: added in main body

Comment: Can you add what you get with your (admittedly incomplete) code?

Answer (score 0):

You could just take one line of the CSV in the **second** format and use the ast module in python to parse it:

```
import ast
index_list = ast.literal_eval("["+first_row+"]")
```

Then `index_list` contains what you want and you just need to take each element in pairs:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(0,index_list,2):
    new_list.append(slice(index_list[i],index_list[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you csv looks something like this:

```
170, 255, 22, 32
125, 320, 14, 24
```

You can just read every two values, and store the `slice()` of these two values in your list:

```
import csv

index_list = []
with open('index_values.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        line = [x.strip() for x in row]
        slices = [slice(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in zip(line[::2], line[1::2])]

        index_list.append(tuple(slices))

print(index_list)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[(slice(170, 255, None), slice(22, 32, None)), (slice(125, 320, None), slice(14, 24, None))]
```

**Note:** [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) has a default step size which is `None` if not specified.

Comment: For me this is simply returning: